# Integral homology groups of free product of cyclic groups

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Please pardon my ignorance when it comes to group homology?  Let $n$ and $m$ be nonnegative integers.  I would like to compute $H_2(\mathbb{Z}/n * \mathbb{Z}/m; \mathbb{Z})$? I am interesed also in $H_2(\mathbb{Z}/m * \mathbb{Z} ; \mathbb{Z})$.  If there is a general method of relating the homology of a free product to the homology of the components that would  be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to answer this question using only the definition of group homology, but here is an alternative method.

Recall that $H_n(G; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_n(K(G, 1); \mathbb{Z})$. Also note that $K(G_1, 1)\vee K(G_2, 1)$ is a $K(G_1\ast G_2, 1)$, so for $n > 0$

\begin{align*}
H_n(G_1\ast G_2; \mathbb{Z}) &\cong H_n(K(G_1\ast G_2, 1); \mathbb{Z})\\ 
&\cong H_n(K(G_1, 1)\vee K(G_2, 1); \mathbb{Z})\\ 
&\cong H_n(K(G_1, 1); \mathbb{Z})\oplus H_n(K(G_2, 1); \mathbb{Z})\\ 
&\cong H_n(G_1; \mathbb{Z})\oplus H_n(G_2; \mathbb{Z}).
\end{align*}

In particular

$$H_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\ast\mathbb{Z}/m; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_2(\mathbb{Z}/2; \mathbb{Z})\oplus H_2(\mathbb{Z}/m; \mathbb{Z}) \cong 0\oplus 0 \cong 0$$

and

$$H_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\ast\mathbb{Z}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_2(\mathbb{Z}/2; \mathbb{Z})\oplus H_2(\mathbb{Z}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong 0\oplus 0 \cong 0.$$

Comment: Thanks- yes this is great thanks.  Why is the wedge of two $K(\pi,1)$'s necessarily still a $K(\pi,1)$?

Comment: The idea is that the universal cover of the wedge is built out of the universal covers of the two factors in some (potentially complicated) way, but the result is still contractible; think about the universal cover of $S^1\vee S^1$ for example. I don't know of a reference for this fact. If I find one, I will let you know.

Comment: One reference for that fact about a wedge of two $K(\pi,1)$'s is Hatcher Section 1.B "$K(G,1)$ spaces and graphs of groups". You can also find this discussed in most works about graphs of groups, for example the monograph of Scott and Wall.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Thanks!